# How to select row with minimum distance

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I am examining the [NYC MVA](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Public-Safety/Motor-Vehicle-Collisions-Crashes/h9gi-nx95) data set. Out of the 1,697,572 records, I've determined that approximately 518,000 are missing ZIP code data:

### Minimal Data Sample

```py
   CRASH DATE CRASH TIME BOROUGH ZIP CODE  LATITUDE  LONGITUDE                      LOCATION
0  07/13/2019       4:10     NaN      NaN  40.69114  -73.80488    POINT (-73.80488 40.69114)
1  06/27/2019      21:30     NaN      NaN  40.58353  -73.98418  POINT (-73.984184 40.583534)
2  07/05/2019      19:40     NaN      NaN  40.61017  -73.92289   POINT (-73.92289 40.610165)
3  06/30/2019       2:30     NaN      NaN  40.70916  -73.84107   POINT (-73.84107 40.709156)
4  07/18/2019      17:50     NaN      NaN  40.74617  -73.82473   POINT (-73.82473 40.746174)
```

```
np.sort(df['ZIP CODE'].astype('str').unique())[:10]
[Out]: array(['     ', '10000', '10000.0', '10001', '10001.0', '10002',
       '10002.0', '10003', '10003.0', '10004'], dtype=object)

empty = np.sort(df['ZIP CODE'].astype('str').unique())[0]
empty_cells = df['ZIP CODE'].isin([empty, np.nan])
len(empty_cells[empty_cells==True])
[Out]: 518797
```

Considering the size of the data set, I know that I can probably correct a lot of these by relying on the Euclidean distance of the closest MVA with ZIP data based on the `LONGITUDE` and `LATITUDE` features.

For starters, I tried to create a new column that would simply find the lowest distance between two longitudinal points using the following:

```
apply(lambda x: df.loc[min(abs(df['LONGITUDE'] - df.loc[x, 'LONGITUDE'])),:])
```

But with this code, my computer's fans nearly send me airborne. I shut it down before my computer did something bad.

I know there's a way to create a column that will allow me to select the minimum Euclidean distance, but I'm just not sure how to write that initial selection code.

Comment: You should probably be using some type of nearest neighbor algorithm to find the closest point to each other point. Doing this by brute force (as you're trying to do) is not very efficient and certainly won't scale to 1m+ records. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#nearest-neighbor-algorithms

Comment: Since this is closed and I can't add an answer, please see this gist with a sample (probably not optimal) solution: https://gist.github.com/gusutabopb/652757f6c3b429a6698081cdbef3518b

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it'll be the best solution for getting ZIP codes, but I use BallTree to get nearest neighbors by distance. Something like this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

tree = BallTree(df_mva[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].values, leaf_size=2)

df['distance_nearest'], df['id_nearest'] = tree.query(
    df[['latitude', 'longitude']].values, # The input array for the query
    k=1, # The number of nearest neighbors
)

df_merged = pd.merge(df,
                df_mva,
                left_on='id_nearest',
                right_index=True)
```

You can adapt it to your code, probably with creating 2 dataframes with `df` being the one without the ZIP codes and `df_mva` being the one with ZIP codes.